# How Can I Make This Script Run For All Members of My Team?

Tags: reactjs, powershell

I've figured out how to get powershell to check for a running DLL and if it's not running, to run it.  I type `npm run passthru` and the script does the work:

```
  "scripts": {
    "passthru": "powershell if (-not (Get-Process -Name MyPassThruApp -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) { dotnet run --project C:/git/MyPassThruApp/MyPassThruApp/MyPassThruApp.csproj }",
  },
```

All well and good, but I want the script to work for any member of my team (on Windows).  I tried adding the path to the .csproj file to the `Path` environment variable (and removing it from the script), but that didn't work - it won't run for me, even after restarting the computer.

Suggestions?

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable only works for automatically resolving paths to executables, not to arbitrary files. You may create a dedicated environment variable, say `MY_CSPROJ_PATH` that specifies the path to the project file and then use it in the path like this: `--project $env:MY_CSPROJ_PATH`.

Comment: @zett42, even though I think it's a terrible idea, PowerShell _does_ execute (open with the default shell action) arbitrary files in `$env:PATH` - see [GitHub issue #12632](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12632).

Comment: Quibble re this question's premise: `Get-Process -Name` doesn't find _DLLs_, it finds _processes_ (`.exe` files on Windows, but without the extension). However, the returned process-info objects have a `.Modules` property that lists the DLL's loaded into that process.

Comment: @zett42, to be clear: that was just an aside - you're correct that an invocation via `dotnet run --project` indeed requires a path based on a  dedicated  environment variable or `$HOME` (which refers to the current user's home dir. in PowerShell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally <sup>1</sup>, as is the case with the `dotnet` CLI, the `PATH` environment variable isn't used to resolve file paths for other file types than executables (e. g. `.exe`, `.cmd`, `.bat`, `.ps1`).

You may create a dedicated environment variable, say `MY_CSPROJ_PATH` that specifies the path to the project file and then use it like this:

```
--project $env:MY_CSPROJ_PATH
```

Alternatively you could use the convention that the project files have to reside in a fixed sub directory of the user's directory, in which case the `$env:HOME` environment variable could be used:

```
--project $env:HOME\projects\MyPassThruApp\MyPassThruApp\MyPassThruApp.csproj
```

---

<sup>[1] As an aside, PowerShell unexpectedly does execute (open with the default shell action) arbitrary files in `$env:PATH` - see [GitHub issue #12632](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12632).</sup>